# IOS 8 my UIScrollView doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, ios8

I have an issue on iOS8 my textview doensn't scroll correctly like it used to be on all previous versions. 
My code is this one :

```
 const BOOL scrollToBottom = (chatTextView.text.length == 0);
    chatTextView.text = getStr;

    NSUInteger length = chatTextView.text.length;
    if (scrollToBottom)
    {
        chatTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(length, 0);
        [chatTextView scrollRangeToVisible:chatTextView.selectedRange];
```

Do you have an idea were the problem might come from ?

In the previous ios version the scroll was always scrolling to bottom when there was new messages in the chatbox. Now the scroll view always refresh to somewhere in the middle of the chat box. I've tried quick hack like NSMakeRange(length+1000, 0); but it doens't change anything

Comment: Can you describe the behaviour you are seeing and the behaviour you would like to see?

Comment: sure
In the previous ios version the scroll was always scrolling to bottom when there was new messages in the chatbox. Now the scroll view always refresh to somewhere in the middle of the chat box. I've tried quick hack like NSMakeRange(length+1000, 0); but it doens't change anything

Comment: Is there any difference if you schedule the scroll later? `dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [chatTextView scrollRangeToVisible:chatTextView.selectedRange];
    });`